# Some SignalR clients unable to receive data from hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

So I have rather odd issues which is affecting multiple clients on my site but not all. We have a SignalR based chat which is then saved to a database (the last 75 lines) for persistence. For some users they can send data to the hub (because the entries are being recorded and saves to the chat table) but what they say is not echoed out to everyone.

Even stranger when one of the guys suggested I log in as him I was able to post to the chat room as him without any issues.

Anyways have any ideas where to start on this one?

Comment: Are clients failing using the same transport than the others? I mean, are all using LongPolling or WebScokets ?

Comment: As far as I can tell WebSockets, the guys having problems are using Chrome and/or Firefox. Then for two users its starting working where it previously was not working then I have another few who its not working at all for still. It really is just odd. Code wise everything seems to check out or it wouldn't work for those who it works for. :)

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Win8. No ideas what others are using.

Comment: Server 08 R2...sorry for the slow reply.